# No blocks available when adding a new post

Tags: posts

In add a new entry. I have no blocks. What is going on?

[image]

Comment: Is that a CPT? Everything is in a foreign language i don't understand, I can't tell

Comment: I had to type out manually the message in the notice with the yellow bar, which reveals your problem, you're editing the page that's used as the blog page. That's why you don't get a block editor UI or post content. This isn't a WP development question but a generic support question. Remember not everybody speaks polish, I had to use Google Translate to even identify that it was Polish ( it also thought it might be slovenian, I don't know )